# Why SNS is not able to send sms through AWS CONSOLE?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send `SMS through console` but apparently i am not receiving any messages.

**What i did so far?**

- Created a topic
- created a subscription of my number and email id.
- published a message

**on my email id i am able to receive messages for the same topic but not on mobile phone.**

even tried other mobile phone,just to be sure that my number is not blocking messages but result is same, **sns SMS is not working through console!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on **Delivery status logging** to see what happened to the message. For example, the carrier might have rejected the message.

From [Viewing Amazon CloudWatch metrics and logs for SMS deliveries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html):

- On Amazon SNS navigation panel, choose Text messaging (SMS).
- On the Text messaging (SMS) page, in the Text messaging preferences section, choose Edit.
- On the Edit text messaging preferences page, in the Delivery status logging section, set Success sample rate to 100%
- Choose Create new service role.
- Choose Create new roles.
- On the SNS is requesting permission to use resources in your account page, choose Allow.
- Choose Save changes.

The output will look similar to:

```json
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "1077257a-92f3-5ca3-bc97-6a915b310625",
        "timestamp": "2016-06-28 00:40:34.559"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "mnc": 0,
        "destination": "+1XXX5550100",
        "priceInUSD": 0.00645,
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "mcc": 0,
        "providerResponse": "Unknown error attempting to reach phone",
        "dwellTimeMs": 1420,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 1692
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

Comment: i followed the above-mentioned steps, but not able to see the output like this in the cloudwatch.

Comment: It can be found in **CloudWatch Logs** (click **Logs** in the CloudWatch window).

Comment: okay i found the log, and it is something like this ( i have trimmed the upper part of output )`"mcc": 404,
        "providerResponse": "Unknown error attempting to reach phone",
        "dwellTimeMs": 193,
        "dwellTimeMsUntilDeviceAck": 276
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
`

Comment: Sounds like the message was sent to the carrier, but they had a problem with delivery. Have you specified a customer Sender ID? Some providers don't like them.

Comment: No i haven't specified `customer Sender ID`